# Adapting to normal gravity after spending time in centrifugal artificial gravity

Tags: biology, artificial-gravity

So pretty much, my world contains a lot of space travel/colonisation, and people live on ships with artificial gravity via centrifugal force. The diameter of these big spinny cylinder things (?) is pretty big, enough that after a while it's not physically nauseating to walk around, though some are a little small.

 My question is, what might happen when someone comes down from a big spinny cylinder thingy and onto a planet/moon with 'true' gravity? I'm guessing being spun around that much might affect your balance system, or the way you move/do things since things behave a little differently, but what other changes might be noticeable? If there even would be changes, since some people have mentioned spinny things (?) that have pretty much no perceivable distances. Note I'm not exactly focused on adapting to different levels of gravity, more adapting to different "types" (?) of gravity; if you know what I mean.

 If there are any things I need to clear up/add/whatever please let me know I'm tired and kinda new.

Comment: "I know being spun around that much would affect your balance system" From curiosity, do you have a reference to it? (to my mind, apart from the Coriolis when riding an elevator - which the space sardines will instinctively await and compensate for - and a different sense of horizon - which has nothing to do with the balance - there shouldn't be any effects)

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi I'm pretty much guessing (so I should probably re-word). In my experience, being spun around for a long time then stopped can make balance do weird things. I'm no expert though, which is why I'm asking you people :)

Comment: Being "spun around" has nothing to do with artificial gravity though? The minimum required size for a comfortable rotating space station is 12 meters. This means that a person inside won't feel any significant differences, so there's nothing to adapt to.

Comment: How long do these travels take ? People live on these space ships for years ?

Comment: @Goodies Long enough for centrifugal gravity to be normal. Months at least.

Comment: @Darth Biomech It doesn't totally answer my question but it is useful. Thanks :) You do have a point, if you're replying to my comment.

Comment: The edit switched the question from "effort of adaptation from centrifugal acceleration to/from gravitational acceleration" to asking "what differences a centrifugal acceleration would impose in the environ perception of those who live under such condition". Unfortunately it does it _after_ an answer geared to the old form has been provided and accepted. My vote goes against reopening the question - my recommendation is to look first for other questions that may provide those details and, _if not found_, raise another question, letting this one closed.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi I myself agree. I tried to close/delete it but it didn't let me as someone had answered. I guess I'll just ... leave it. Also I didn't edit my base question ... did someone else?

Comment: So this question has caused a lot of unnecessary stress ... I don't like it (and I don't think the community likes it either) and I want to get rid of it, but I can't because it's been answered. Is there any way I can just get it locked or something?

Comment: @sprout It's closed already, don't worry too much.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi But people can still interact with it ... maybe I'm just getting too stressed over nothing.

Comment: @sprout "maybe I'm just getting too stressed over nothing." at least on the "over nothing" part, I'm pretty sure about it.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi Yeah.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there would be significant issues: true, the spinning habitat might influence the labyrinth in the inner ear and with it the equilibrium, however transition to normal gravity would necessarily happen through a stage of microgravity, which would very likely reset the system and mitigate the transition.

What probably will take some readjusting is the adaptation to the horizon and the related perception of the vanishing point, which in an artificial gravity environment bends "up", while in a normal gravity environment bends "down", as depicted in Kubrick's 2001 A space odyssey.

[image]